# How to change the camera position in threebox?

Tags: javascript, three.js, mapbox, threebox

I'm using ThreeBox to build and design a map with 3D Objects.  Is there any way to change the camera position in ThreeBox?

I am supposed to put the camera behind an object and make it navigate in the third person, but my first problem is how to position the camera behind the object.

Comment: please try to be more specific or at least put minimum effort in explaining the problem.

Comment: @Epimetheus I edited the question to specify the problem.

Comment: sorry,jscastro.I have a problem here that I need to trouble you
这是[链接](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70300674/can-threebox-use-post-progress-like-threejs-webglrendertarget-shaderpass-and-eff)！

Answer (score 0):

[Threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox) uses Mapbox camera to sync the perspective, so you only have to change the map camera view through [`map.flyTo`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#flyto) where you can specify coords, zoom, pitch and bearing to find your desired position. You have an example of [mapbox `flyTo`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/flyto-options/).

Indeed I personally use this feature in all my projects adding these attributes to the `feature.properties` that I use to generate every 3D object